# Using SimpleSideDrawer in android

Tags: java, android

I am using simplesidedrawer library for android.But the problem is that the static xml file has been linked to the drawer.So if i want to add content dynamically to the right or the left side it is not coming.

The code which i have done is as follows:

```
package com.navdrawer.demo.simple;

import com.navdrawer.SimpleSideDrawer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;
    Button btn1;
    RightFragment rf;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
        mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);
           findViewById(R.id.leftBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mNav.toggleLeftDrawer();
            }
        });


        mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple);

        findViewById(R.id.rightBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                mNav.toggleRightDrawer();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

The right fragment:(i tried adding content dynamically but it does not work)

```
package com.navdrawer.demo.simple;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RightFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lv_countries;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple, container, false);
         lv_countries=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
         String[] values = new String[] { 
                 "Android List View", 
                 "Adapter implementation",
                 "Simple List View In Android",
                 "Create List View Android", 
                 "Android Example", 
                 "List View Source Code", 
                 "List View Array Adapter", 
                 "Android Example List View" 
                };
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
         lv_countries.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i am abandoning the navigation drawer approach...

Comment: I have tried that but the issue is that there is only one button on the left while using navigation drawer.The above method gives me two buttons.

Comment: Sorry man ,running against a deadline so am nervous.So can you fix this issue.?

Comment: The issue is this: In the line mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple); The static xml page is set in the right drawer.I want to add content to this xml file through java code.So i tried putting the required code in a fragment(RightFragment).But the code added dynamically is not shown in the xml.

Comment: @MikeM.So can you tell me as to where i should modify in main activity so as to load the java code for rightfragment.

Comment: @MikeM.I am waiting for your response.

Comment: Do you need Fragments? If so, you shouldn't be using the same layout for the drawer as you are for the Fragment. The drawer layout should contain a View to be replaced by the Fragment in a standard FragmentTransaction. If you don't really need Fragments, and the ListView is in `activity_behind_right_simple`, just move the ListView setup to the Activity's `onCreate()`.

Comment: But the listview is in the activity that pops up on sliding , not on the main activity.

Comment: Which Activity "pops up on sliding"?

Comment: There is no activity specified for that xml file.It is a static file.I wanted to add contents to that static file by creating a fragment activity.

Comment: You only have one Activity. The drawer is not an Activity. The drawer is contained in the Activity's layout. It doesn't need to contain a Fragment to dynamically alter the contents. Did you try moving the ListView setup as I described? If `lv_countries` is in `activity_behind_right_simple`, then put the setup after the call to `mNav.setRightBehindContentView()`.

Comment: tried that didnt help

Comment: Works for me. If you're using the sample on github, change the layout so that it only contains the ListView. No ScrollView or TextViews.